# Мониторинг кластера kubernetes вне кластера

Tags: devops, kubernetes, мониторинг, grafana, prometheus

На YandexCloud у меня развёрнут кластер k8s (не managed). Разворачивал через terraform и kubespay. В итоге у меня есть 1 управляющий сервер SRV (с которого разворачивал кластер, он же гитлаб-раннер) и несколько нод самого кластера.
[image: инстансы]

---

В кластере через helm поднято простое тестовое Django-приложение в связке с Postgres.
[image: поды]

---

**Что мне нужно сделать?**
У меня есть задача развернуть мониторинг на управляющем сервере SRV и собирать метрики и логи:

- с самого сервера SRV,
- со всех нод кластера,
- с работающих в k8s контейнеров.

А так же настроить отправку уведомлений в телеграм.
Стэк мониторинга: Prometheus + Loki + Grafana + Alertmanager.

Пересмотрел кучу гайдов. Везде мониторинг разворачивают непосредственно в кластере k8s. Но если вдруг кубер умрёт, то и мониторинг умрёт. Поэтому его необходимо развернуть на отдельном инстансе SRV.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

P.S.
Я еще чайник в DevOps, поэтому буду рад пошаговому гайду.